# Pass one query value to another query in SQL Server

Tags: t-sql

I need to pass one query values to another query as "table name" and "column name" like below

```
SELECT Value1 AS [MyTableName],Value2 AS [MyColName]
FROM MyTable
```

Pass the above result to below query as follows.

```
SELECT * FROM [MyTableName]
WHERE ColumnValue = MyColName
```

In this case MyTableName is Value1 from the above result and MyColName is Value2.
Is it possible to combine the above result into a single query.

Comment: No, this is not possible. The only way to create a query with *variable* table name is to build it on string level and execute this string using `EXEC()` or `sp_executesql()`. And don't forget to ensure that the values will **never ever** be used for SQL injection...

Answer (score 1):

You need to use dynamic sql.

To protect against injection, we will use these:
1) sp_executesql, so that we can do 3)
2) quotename for the system objects (ie: table and column) names
3) pass the column value through a parameter

```
declare 
     @mytablename nvarchar(128)
    ,@mycolname nvarchar(128)
    ,@mycolvalue nvarchar(max) -- or whatever your column type is
    ,@stmt nvarchar(max)
    ,@params nvarchar(max)

select @mytablename=quotename(Value1),@mycolname=quotename(Value2) AS [MyColName]
FROM MyTable

set @mycolvalue = 'myColValueData' -- or whatever the value is
set @stmt=
N'select * from '+@mytablename
+nchar(13)+nchar(10)+'where '+@mycolname+' = @mycolvalue'
set @params='@mycolvalue nvarchar(max)'  -- or whatever your column type is

exec sp_executesql(@stmt,@params,@mycolvalue=@mycolvalue)
```